# Codeigniter : Jquery fill the textbox based on combobox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, combobox, codeigniter-2

I am Nubie in JQuery especially in ajax..
I have read articles about dropdown combobox (read from database) then fills other textbox (read from database based on combobox data) but I have confused

I Need Jquery / Ajax / something to show it

can someone solve my problem and explain to me..

**Controller**

```
public function tambah()
{
    $cek = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if(empty($cek))
    {
        header('location:'.base_url().'app_admin');
    }
    else
    {
        $d['nama_madrasah'] = "";
        $d['nsm'] = "";
        $d['provinsi'] = "";
        $d['alamat'] = "";
        $d['kecamatan'] = "";
        $d['kab_kota'] = "";
        $d['jenis_bantuan'] = "";
        $d['jenjang'] = "";
        $d['th_ang'] = "";
        $d['sumber_dana'] = "";
        $d['tahap_pencairan'] = "";
        $d['st'] = "tambah";

        $d['dt_nsm'] = $this->app_model->ShowNSMMaster();

        $this->load->view("app_admin/madrasah/input",$d);
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
<select data-placeholder="Cari NSM..." class="chzn-select" style="width:260px;" tabindex="2" name="nsm" id="dt_nsm"  >
              <?php
              if($st=='edit')
              {
              ?>
                <option value="<?php echo '$nsm'; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo '$nsm'; ?></option>
              <?php
              }
              else
              {
              ?> 
              <option value="" selected="selected">- Pilih -</option>
                <?php
                foreach($dt_nsm->result_array() as $dp1)
                {
          ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $dp1['nsm']; ?>"><?php echo $dp1['nsm']; ?> | <?php echo $dp1['nama_madrasah']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            }
          ?>
              </select>
            </span></div>
            <label class="control-label" for="nama_madrasah">Nama Madrasah </label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="span" name="nama_madrasah" id="nama_madrasahx" value="<?php echo $nama_madrasah; ?>" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label" for="alamat">Alamat</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="span" name="alamat" id="alamatx" value="<?php echo $alamat; ?>" placeholder="">
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dt_nsm').on('change', function(){
    dt_nsm = $('#dt_nsm option:selected').val(); // the dropdown item selected value
    $.ajax({
        type :'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data : { dt_nsm : dt_nsm },
        url : 'getresult.php',
        success : function(result){
         $('#nama_madrasahx).val(result['nama_madrasahx']); 
         $('#kecamatanx).val(result['kecamatanx']);  
        }
    });});
    </script>
```

**getresult.php**

```
<?php 
require_once ('../config/db.config.php');

$dt_nsm = $_POST['dt_nsm'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM bantuan WHERE nsm = '$nsm' ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

[image: Form View]

Thanks For your time. Need Advice !

Comment: did you try something

Comment: @MeeneshJain : I try in 2 days but my JS not upload at this. thanks

Comment: upload your js also,

Comment: @MeeneshJain : thanks for response. I upload my JS. maybe you can help me. please

Answer (score 0):

change

```
foreach($dt_nsm->result_array() as $dp1)
```

to

```
foreach($dt_nsm->result_array() as $key=>$dp1)
```

Comment: sorry sir. I need JQuery.

Comment: oh sorry , if you want to use JQuery to achieve these function ,you'd better  package your data to json , and then use "$.getJSON" to get the data

Comment: anyone can help me. pleaseee